# Reading parsing JSON

Tags: java, json

i have a JSON string

```
   [
   {"created_at":"Thu Jan 24 07:27:12 +0000 2013",
     "id":294345590119227392,
     "user":{
             "id":213539531,
              "name":"Hamid",
              "screen_name":"HamidMirGEO",
             },
     "retweeted":false
     }]
```

Parsing Using following code

```
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
        for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(i);
            x += "Date:" + post.getString("created_at") + "\n";
            x += "Post:" + post.getString("text") + "\n\n";
            x += "Pp:" + post.getString("screen_name") + "\n\n";//error reading this
        }
```

Successfully parse first two but facing problem reading the data in second braces {};
any solution of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
x += "Pp:" + post.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name") + "\n\n";
```

Instead of:

```
x += "Pp:" + post.getString("screen_name") + "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

`screen_name` is in a nested object. Use this code:

```
post.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

To get screen_name you need access the `JSONObject` it is contained in. like so:

```
JSONObject user = post.getJSONObject("user");
user.getString("screen_name") // this will return the screen_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra coma after "HamidMirGeo", remove it.